# How do I navigate to a contacts address using my voice

Tags: google-now, voice-command, google-maps-navigation, google-voice-actions

This seems like it should be easy but I'd I say to Google now or the Google search all "Navigate to Contact Name" it just does a Google search. Contact is saved and synced to Google. Doesn't seem to work with any of my contacts.

I am pretty sure that this used to work...

Thanks

Comment: I want to navigate to them - i.e. open Google maps and drive there.

Comment: well, I don't believe that is possible for a privacy leak....

Comment: @maxpesa I doubt that: the contact data is stored on Google servers, so whom to leak to?

Comment: And "phone Contact Name" works...

Comment: If that was possible, stalking would be so damn easy... For sure the other person needs to have "Home" set in GMaps, but I don't know anything else...

Comment: This is for a contact that I have entered myself. An address I knew already.

Comment: Have you already solved the problem? lf so please accept or add an answer to this question.

Comment: 6 1/2 years later and I'm still having the same problem.  "Hey google, call XXX" works just fine.  So it understands my voice and can access my address book.  But "navigate XXX" confuses google.  It does a web search and ignores my contacts.  I have similar results if I open the map instead of google assistant.  

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me.

- Try updating your [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app.
- Try enabling **Google Settings > Accounts & privacy > Personal results** and **Contact recognition**. Alternatively, you can get to Google Settings from the bottom of the Google Now app (you may have to scroll down).

[image: Google Now]

Comment: That's odd, it worked on my tablet (but asked me about allowing contact recognition first). I'll try and see if I can find a contact recognition option.

Comment: I found it, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Google has changed the workflow of the settings. I thought **Google Settings > Search & Now > Phone search > Contacts** is enough, but I can't get it to work...